# Why an EXPLAIN statement is generated when doing a simple query?

Tags: php, mysql, mdb2

I am using MDB2 to make query to my MySQL database but when I query the database, the MySQL log trace 2 statements: the first one is an explain statement and the second is my query.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";
$mdb2Instance = new MDB2();
$options = array(
        'portability' => MDB2_PORTABILITY_ALL ^ MDB2_PORTABILITY_FIX_CASE,
    );
$connection = $mdb2Instance->singleton($dsn, null);
$connection->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
$connection->query($sql);
```

And I get the following log in MySQL:

```
    5 Init DB   cma
    5 Query EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    5 Query SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    5 Quit
```

Can someone explain me what's happening and how to prevent this?

Regards
Alban

Comment: this doesnt happen if you use the builtin mysql_query() calls? Is your fetch returning the proper value of 1?

Comment: The fetch value is correct.
How to use the mysql_query() in combination with MDB2?

Comment: seems to be MDB2 has built in feature to do a query execution plan before actually execute the sql

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by PHP configuration directive `>mysql.trace-mode`

With this setting set to On, every query is preceded by `EXPLAIN` query. The PHP manual doesn't say that this behaviour occurs and it's a shame for it can break things badly (a lot of apps counting on queries like `FOUND_ROWS()`).

Setting it to Off should resolve your problem.